# Black booting screen on Mac Mini using Dell D6000 dock

Tags: macos, dock, macos-mojave

### Details

I have Mac Mini (late 2014) running macOS Mojave 10.14.2 and recently bought Dell D6000 dock. I connected 2x Dell U2715H monitors using DP ports to the dock, installed all necessary drivers (DisplayLink 5.0.1), and gave the security permissions for that software. That works.

### Issue

At this point, the monitors work well while my Mac is turned on or is waking up from sleep. However, when I try to restart the computer, I get a **black screen** during the booting phase.

*Current workaround (1)*: Choose the correct account and enter the password without seeing anything.

*Current workaround (2)*: Connect one of the monitors using HDMI straight to Mac Mini (not using the dock).

After going past the password step by logging in, both monitors turn on and work properly.

### Fix

Help me to find a fix for the issue of having a black screen during the booting phase.

Comment: During the boot phase, DisplayLink drivers will not be available. I’m quite sure you won’t be able to work around that. // Surely your displays have multiple inputs. Make use of that fact and connect them directly to your Mac Mini for superior performance and support. Connect them to your docking station, too, to allow docked devices to use them.

Comment: That was what I was thinking. However, thought that somebody might have created some workaround loading those drivers during the boot phase. Thanks, anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, with FileVault turned on... only workaround is to wake the monitor (such as displaying its menu) then turn on Mac mini within a second or two. Seems mini cannot wake display properly.

With FileVault Off, I have no problems, just need to wait about 20 seconds. Monitor comes on, then off, 20 seconds later login appears.